# Gitlab unable to create blank repository

Tags: amazon-ec2, gitlab, gitlab-ce

I have installed the Gitlab Community Edition (v16.2) on an EC2 Instance,
I'm unable to create a blank project on the same, When creating I'm getting the error as[Image of Faild to create repository, project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhNtK.png)
[Screenshot of the Gitlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKyKO.png)

I wanted to create a blank project, but it refers to the repository creation.
need help,to debug and solve the issue

I tried to install the gitlab-shell, application again hoping to solve the issue, but failed
And I followed this thread https://forum.gitlab.com/t/failed-to-create-repository/334, this too didn't work.